# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).is not a function - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Thats my page. http://netsportsinc.biz/?p=136

On console accuse "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).is not a function"

I have no idea how to fix that. Already tried all solutions on StackOverflow.

Please help me
Thanks
Raf

Comment: jQuery is being imported as `$` you could try `window.jQuery = $` some place before `jQuery(...).seg_rfkt_portfolio_ajax` is called, but after `$` is imported? In either case `jQuery('.seg-rfktportfolio').seg_rfkt_portfolio_ajax` is `undefined` though...?

Comment: I get `TypeError: jQuery(...).seg_rfkt_portfolio_ajax is not a function` which is an entirely different message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have your syntax for ajax as below :

```
 $.ajax({url: "test", success: function(result){
    ...
 }});
```

or

```
 jQuery(...).ajax({url: "test", success: function(result){
    ...
 }});
```

seg_rfkt_portfolio_ajax  is not a defined function.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much!How did you debug?

Comment: it's simple javascript error message. when you click on that it will show you which line it's generated. and you can find out the error. please accept answer if it is helpful